# I have designed a single port RAM in verilog, but I am unable to do the vertical and horizontal expansion of RAM memory. Can you help me in it?

Tags: verilog, ram, expansion

Here is the code for the RAM module

module syncRAM( dataIn,dataOut,address,cs,we,oe,clk);

```
parameter ADR   = 8;
parameter DAT   = 8;
parameter DPTH  = 8;

input   [DAT-1:0]  dataIn;
output reg [DAT-1:0]  dataOut;
input   [ADR-1:0]  address;
input cs,we,clk,oe; 
reg [DAT-1:0] mem [DPTH-1:0];

always @ (posedge clk)
begin : MEM_READ
  if (cs && !we && oe) begin
     mem[address] = dataIn;
  end
end

always @ (posedge clk)
begin : MEM_WRITE
    if ( cs && we ) begin
         dataOut = mem[address];
    end
end
```

endmodule

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by vertical and horizontal expansion? And please format your code correctly by indenting the whole think with 4 spaces or adding ``` at the start and end.

Comment: can you show us what you have tried? it might clarify the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are asking is a generic RAM code where you can modify Depth and Width of Memory. Here is a sample code, might not be up-to your specification

```
module RAM (

                ReadAddress  ,
                ReadEn       ,
                dataOut      ,

                WriteEn      ,
                WriteAddress ,
                dataIn       ,

                clk          ,
                rst_n                   
             );

parameter DAT  = 32           ;
parameter DPTH = 1024         ;
parameter ADR  = $clog2(DPTH) ; // 10

input      [ ADR  - 1 : 0 ] ReadAddress ;
input                      ReadEn       ;
output reg [ DAT  - 1 : 0 ] dataOut     ;

input                 WriteEn           ;
input [ ADR - 1 : 0 ] WriteAddress      ;
input [ DAT - 1 : 0 ] dataIn            ;

input clk                               ;
input rst_n                             ;

reg [ DAT - 1 : 0 ] ram [0 : DPTH-1] ; // DAT x DPTH = 32 x 1024

integer i ;

   always@( posedge clk )
      begin
         if ( !rst_n )
            begin
               dataOut  <= { DAT { 1'b0 } } ; 
            end
         else 
            begin     
               if ( WriteEn )                           // write
                  begin
                     ram [ WriteAddress ] <= dataIn  ; 
                  end

               if (ReadEn)                              // read
                  begin                                
                     dataOut <= ram [ ReadAddress   ] ;
                  end
            end

      end
endmodule
```

Here the parameters define the size of RAM module:

**DAT** is width of your data being written to and read from RAM.
**DPTH** is size or no of entries in your RAM.
**ADR** is size of Index used to traverse into RAM.

Here **ADR** is calculated according to the **DPTH** i.e. No of entries of RAM.
***$clog2*** is used to take log2() of DPTH and ceil it to the next integer value.

In current example $clog2(DPTH) is $clog2(1024) is equal to 10 the size od **ADR**

Thus **ADR** is used as size of Read and Write Address Signal.

By changing **DAT** and **DPTH** you can get RAM of any dimension.

I hope this is what you mean by ***Horizontal or Vertical Expansion***